# Infinite recursion in Java with splay trees

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am trying to write a "contains" method for a splay tree to figure out if a node is already in the tree. I give this method a node to start searching and a string key to use find the corresponding node. I think I have a pretty good handle on recursion, but I am stumped by this. I've bolded the two lines that are causing the infinite recursion, but I'm stuck because, unless you somehow have a tree with an infinite number of elements, wouldn't the left and/or right elements have to be null at some point? They cannot be != to null forever! I might be losing my mind but I would very much appreciate any clarification on how to create a stronger base case.

tldr: how is it possible for this function to recurse infinitely when we have to run into null at some point?!

```
public BST_Node containsNode(BST_Node node, String s) {
  BST_Node result = null;
  if (node == null) {
  return null;
  }

  if (node.data.compareTo(s) == 0) {
  splay(node);
  return node;
  }

  if (node.left != null) {
      result = containsNode(node.left, s); //recursion here
  }

  if (result == null && node.right != null) {
      result = right.containsNode(node.right, s); //recursion here
  }
  return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should really step through this with a debugger. I have a feeling it has to do with the way you are returning your result pointer.

Comment: `right != null` ... you mean `node.right != null` ?

Comment: Yeah right is node.right forgot to include that. And yes I have been struggling with the debugger for the past hour lol... I agree

Comment: It might be helpful if you include some data for a sample tree that we could try to logically run against your code.  I don't see an obvious problem right now.

Comment: what does your `splay` function do?

Comment: Is it a binary search tree ? In that case you should recursively search the ``left`` or ``right`` subtree in dependence of the value.